# MongoDB: Profiler - Query details

Tags: mongodb, profiler

I need a way to follow queries performance, run-time, statistics and more on my mongodb system.

I'm trying to use the profiler... now, because I have sharding. I enabled profiling by running on each mongod instance in the cluster the following command:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

And the profiler is running.

But when I trying to find running queries (with "find()") on my system I doesn't find anything !
I'm running on mongod:

```
db.system.profile.find({"op":"query"}).limit(1).pretty()
```

and the result set is:

```
{
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "test.system.profile",
        "query" : {
                "op" : {
                        "ns" : "query"
                }
        },
        "ntoreturn" : 0,
        "ntoskip" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 2931,
        "nscannedObjects" : 2931,
        "keyUpdates" : 0,
        "numYield" : 0,
        "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                        "r" : NumberLong(1261),
                        "w" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                        "r" : NumberLong(2),
                        "w" : NumberLong(1)
                }
        },
        "nreturned" : 0,
        "responseLength" : 20,
        "millis" : 1,
        "execStats" : {
                "type" : "COLLSCAN",
                "works" : 2933,
                "yields" : 22,
                "unyields" : 22,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 0,
                "needTime" : 2932,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "docsTested" : 2931,
                "children" : [ ]
        },
        "ts" : ISODate("2016-06-08T11:30:11.029Z"),
        "client" : "127.0.0.1",
        "allUsers" : [ ],
        "user" : ""
}
```

I want to get queries that users\ applications are running... must of those queries are "find" queries...

- How can I get the query syntax from the system.profile collection?
- How can I filter by specific query? get specific query with his running data (runtime, indexes used...).
- I have to query system.profile collection on all mongod instances? there is no one place that I can query all data from system.profile?

Thanks :)

Comment: OK... I found this query very useful:
db.system.profile.find({"op":"<query,insert,update,remove>","client" : "<IP>","ns" : "<db.collection>"}).sort({ts:-1}).limit(1).pretty()

and I understood that in "query" I can see the parameters that find() is sending
for example: db.test.find({"_id":1 ,"text":"Sample Text"})

the results will be:
"query" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "text" : "Sample Text"
        }


Is there a way to see the actual query from the profiler results? 
to see: db.test.find({"_id":1 ,"text":"Sample Text"})

Thanks

Comment: My main question is... How I can filter a spastic query among all data that in system.profile ???

Comment: I hoped finding the entry in the `mongod.log` file is an option, but it seems to be in the same format as in the profiler output...